# Sorting xmlnodelist with XPATH, and convert back to xmlnodelist

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xmlnodelist in C# I would like sort by ID without creating arrays.
The XML data is loaded into a dynamic table I've created.
I haven't studied a lot XPATH but I figured out by Googling the attached code could work.
Howevern, I would like to get the sorted output back as an xmlnodelist in order to create the dynamic table easily.
Is this possible?

(http://forums.asp.net/t/1226980.aspx):

```
public partial class DefaultSamePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
//a public var XmlNodeList, in order to use it both in sortNodeList and another function
    XmlNodeList sortedNodes;
}

   void sortNodeList()
{
        XPathDocument myQuiz = new XPathDocument(Server.MapPath("quiz.xml"));
        XPathNavigator nav = myQuiz.CreateNavigator();
        XPathExpression myExp = nav.Compile("//question");
        myExp.AddSort("@id", XmlSortOrder.Descending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number);
        XPathNodeIterator iter = nav.Select(myExp);
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            // is this possible?
            sortedNodes = iter.Current.Value;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> However, I would like to get the sorted output back as an `XmlNodeList` in order to create the dynamic table easily

You can't.  In order to have an `XmlNodeList`, you need `XmlNode`s, and an `XmlNode` has to belong to an `XmlDocument`.  And you're not creating an `XmlDocument`.

Sort of the whole point of the `XPathDocument` that it doesn't create `XmlNode` objects.  The reason to write code that uses `IXPathNavigable` is that if you have to navigate through tens of thousands of nodes to find six of them, your code doesn't have to create tens of thousands of `XmlNode` objects first.  That's the main reason why `XPathNavigator` code is much faster than code that uses `XmlDocument`.

If you're going to use `IXPathNagivable` anywhere in your code, you should be using it everywhere.  Don't write methods that take `XmlNode` and `XmlNodeList` as parameters; write methods that take `XPathNavigator` and `XPathNodeIterator` instead.

For instance, if you're populating a table from XML data, you might presently have methods that look like:

```
public DataTable PopulateTable(DataTable t, XmlNodeList nodes)
{
   foreach (XmlNode n in nodes)
   {
      CreateRow(t, n);
   }
}

private void CreateRow(DataTable t, XmlNode n)
{
   DataRow r = t.NewRow();
   t["foo"] = n.GetAttribute("foo");
   t["bar"] = n.GetAttribute("bar");
   t.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

You could just as easily write that code this way:

```
public void PopulateTable(DataTable t, XPathNodeIterator iter)
{
   foreach (XPathNavigator n in iter)
   {
      CreateRow(t, n);
   }
}

private void CreateRow(DataTable t, XPathNavigator n)
{
   DataRow r = t.NewRow();
   t["foo"] = n.GetAttribute("foo", "");
   t["bar"] = n.GetAttribute("bar", "");
   t.Rows.Add(r);
}
```